# compiler error saying invalid initialization of reference of type something& from expression of type something*

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a  function prototype like

```
test(something &)
```

and i am doing

```
something *ss = new something();
```

and i say

```
test(ss)
```

compiler complains saying initialization of reference of type something& from expression  something * .

but isn't that new returns the address and ss must point to that address ! so if test is expecting a reference  is not it ss represents a reference ?

Answer (score 3):

Your function expects a normal `something` object. You don't need to use a pointer here:

```
something ss;

test(ss);
```

When your function signature looks like `f(T&)`, it means that it accepts a reference to a `T` object. When the signature is `f(T*)`, it means that it accepts a *pointer* to a `T` object.

Answer (score 2):

Your function expects a reference to `something`, and you are passing it a *pointer* to `something`. You need to de-reference the pointer:

```
test(*ss);
```

That way the function takes a reference to the object pointed at by `ss`. If you had a `something` object, you could pass that directly to:

```
something sss;
test(sss); // test takes a reference to the sss object.
```

Comment: can you please explain me y we have to do this as ss already contains a address and test also expects an address

Comment: @bana because a reference is not a pointer. A reference to a type `T`, say `T&`, is like an alias for an object of that type. If your function expected a pointer, then you could pass the address of a `something` object, or the `ss` pointer itself.

Comment: @bana: `test` does *not* expect an address.  Addresses are stored in pointers.  So if `test` expected an address, its declaration would look like this: `void test(something*);`

Comment: You can see a reference as a "pointer which is sure not to be NULL". This may help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you are confused by [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) and address of variable.

If your function prototype is:

```
test(something &)
```

You could call it with `something object`:

```
something ss;
test(ss);
```

You could call it with `something pointer`:

```
 something *ss = new something();
 test(*ss);
```

If your function is:

```
test(something *)
```

You could call:

```
something *ss = new something();
test(ss);
```