# c++: "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘List&’ from a temporary of type ‘List*’"

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

I have the following function set up that parses a file into a List class set up. I'm getting a "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘List&’ from a temporary of type ‘List*’" error. What does this mean?

```
void parseFile (string filename, List& list)
{
    ifstream file (filename);
    // Parsing code
    file.close();
    return;
}

int main ()
{
    List list;
    parseFile ("file.xml", &list); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [compiler error saying invalid initialization of reference of type something& from expression of type something\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823528/compiler-error-saying-invalid-initialization-of-reference-of-type-something-fro)

Comment: If you're wanting to pass a pointer, you should edit the `parseFile` declaration to `void parseFile (string filename, List* list)`

Comment: You don't need to explicitly say list is a ref by doing `&list` in C++ as in C#, just use list as argument, you're using the address operator on the list now, that's why it's erroring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error messages don't get much clearer than that. You're passing the address (a `List*`) of `list` to a function that's declared to take a lvalue reference (`List&`).

Write `parseFile ("file.xml", list);` instead.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I last did this sorta stuff in C++. The problem I have with this method is that it doesn't let me call any of List's methods without causing a segfault. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: That's a problem with `List` class (or some other code) which I know nothing about, so can't help you with that.

Comment: That's fine. I didn't think it was that, but I'll take a closer look. Thanks for your help